# What is this object seen on the floor in a cutscene from chapter 2 of Bayonetta?

Tags: object-identification, bayonetta

This cutscene is from from chapter 2 of *Bayonetta*.

What is this object on the cell floor seen at 28:30?

[[image: screenshot of object]][2]

[image][image][image]

Comment: Could you obtain a more clear image? What is your doubt?

Comment: The cutscene is not very clear and it’s fast ,I can’t recognize those forms on the flor

Comment: Can you provide any sense of scale?  Is this centimetres across or metres?

Comment: I think it's a person (Bayo?). They're shown sitting up in the same spot in the next shot.

Comment: Can somebody explain what is this picture ?I can’t identify this “thing” on the cell floor

Comment: is the view from top through the wire to the bottom (and so the white thing is the question) or is it from front and the wire is the backside and the dark thing is the question? You may get more answers, when the answerer do not need to look the video...

Comment: The dark thing is the question ,those drawings below the the dark thing

Comment: Anthony, I can't see what you're seeing. There's  a sort of black isosceles triangle, point upwards. Is that the left leg bent you are seeing? Because I'm sure it's on the other side of the bars. I think it's part of the person's clothes.  A hooded cloak with a light outer side, and a dark inner side, I think.

Comment: I mean the picture I uploaded above the hooded white man,hes shadow is reflecting(dark hood) right?

Comment: @Pete I've deleted my previous comment, because now that I've had time to actually look into this more (i.e. not using the pictures in the question), what I thought I was seeing wasn't entirely correct. [This video](https://youtu.be/o_BZ8XUXdms?t=2611) seems to be better quality. It looks to be a young girl lying on the ground; possibly the same young girl that Bayonetta just met (triggering the flashback), but I can't be sure.